# VB form validation issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, validation, focus

I am doing form validation in VB, I validate the text field data by using `txtName_LostFocus` function, and on wrong input I used `txtName.Focus()`. It works well for me. But problem is that as for as, user does not input valid text, my EXIT button also does not works. Is there any solution to correct this solution.

Comment: can you place the code what you're doing exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The problems you're experiencing are a result of not reading the documentation carefully. The docs for the [`LostFocus` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) make very clear that you should *not* attempt to set the focus (e.g., by calling the [`Focus` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx)) in the handler method for this event:

> **Caution**
>
> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding. For more information, see the `WM_KILLFOCUS` topic in the "Keyboard Input Reference" section, and the "Message Deadlocks" section of the "About Messages and Message Queues" topic in the MSDN library at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library.

A better solution is to handle the [`Validating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx). You'll perform your input validating inside the `Validating` event handler method, which is raised automatically by the .NET Framework.

If the input is valid, you do nothing. If the input is *not* valid, you set the `Cancel` property of the `CancelEventArgs` parameter to `true`, causing all of the downstream events to be suppressed.

```
Private Sub myTextBox_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                 ByVal e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
                             Handles myTextBox.Validating
    If Not Valid(myTextBox.Text) Then
        ' Validation failed, so cancel the event and pre-select the text.
        e.Cancel = True
        myTextBox.Select(0, myTextBox.Text.Length)

        ' Optionally (but recommended): Set an ErrorProvider control.
        ' errorProvider.SetError(myTextBox, "Invalid input")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine but User can not exit until valid information. I want, that user may leave/exit the form, may he/she inputed wrong text

Comment: @Shah That, too, is covered in the linked documentation. Set the `CausesValidation` property of your "Exit" button (and any other controls you wish) to `true` so that clicking it does not raise the `Validating` or `Validated` events.